# Use dynamically populated string async task

Tags: android

I have a string that is being populated by edit text fields when someone enters an address to get the lat and long from the address.

```
    final String specAddressStr = specAddress.getText().toString() + " " + specCity.getText().toString() + "," + " " + specState.getText().toString() + " " + specZip.getText().toString();
```

I need to use this string in an async task, but when I try and reference it and set the string as a global variable to use it in the tasks, it causes the app to force close. Is there a different way to use a dynamically populated string in an async task that I am missing? Here is the async task code as requested:

```
    public class LowSignal extends Activity {

String specAddressStr;

private class processLatandLong extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        List<Address> foundGeocode = null;

        // find the addresses by using getFromLocationName() method with the given address

        try {

            foundGeocode = new Geocoder(LowSignal.this).getFromLocationName(specAddressStr, 1);
            foundGeocode.get(0).getLatitude(); // getting latitude
            foundGeocode.get(0).getLongitude();// getting longitude



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (foundGeocode !=null) {
            returnedLat.setText(String.valueOf(foundGeocode.get(0).getLatitude()));
            returnedLong.setText(String.valueOf(foundGeocode.get(0).getLongitude()));
        } else {
            returnedLat.setText("Unable to find Latitude. Please try again.");
            returnedLong.setText("Unable to find Longitude. Please try again.");
        }


        return null;

    }
```

And here is where I am calling the task:

```
    public void getLatandLong(View v) {

    String specAddressStr = specAddress.getText().toString() + " "
                + specCity.getText().toString() + "," + " "
                + specState.getText().toString() + " "
                + specZip.getText().toString();

        new processLatandLong().execute(specAddressStr);

    }
}
```

Comment: Pass it as an argument to the AsyncTask constructor?

Comment: or as an argument to execute ? (also, post stacktrace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass String to `AsyncTask.execute(Your_String)` for accessing Vlue in `doInBackground` as :

```
    specAddressStr = specAddress.getText().toString() + " " + 
                     specCity.getText().toString() + "," + " " + 
                     specState.getText().toString() + " " + 
                     specZip.getText().toString();
    new LongOperation().execute(specAddressStr);

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
               String stredittext=params[0];
            }
// your code....
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it for the most part. Do I still need to add the strings as global variables? I am curious about String stredittext=params[0];  as well. I can post the code I am using if I need to. I am sorry to ask so many questions, I am still learning async tasks and how they work.

Comment: @Jasonwilliams10 : in doInBackground use `getFromLocationName(params[0], 1);` instead of `getFromLocationName(specAddressStr, 1);` you have any issue in using `params[0]`